# discord bot when somebody says a certain word (two words) bot relpys

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

im trying to make a discord bot on py and im new to py

im trying to make my bot reply when someones says certain word

for example if there is "bot" and "not" in sentace bot reply with "do you think bot are not working?"
i made this code

```
    if message.content.find("bot" and "not") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("do you think bots aren't working? contact @sdu or ask other player in #bot channal")
        await message.channel.send("sorry for inconvenient")
```

but if i only say "not" bot will reply

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're running into has nothing to do with the bot, it's how Python's boolean evaluation works. If you run a binary operator like `or` or `and`, then Python will return the first thing that determines its truth value.

For `x and y`, Python will return `False` if `x` evaluates to false and if `x` evaluates to `True`, Python will return the value of `y`, as this determines the truth value of the `and` statement.

Given that a non-empty string evaluates to `True`, the output in your example will always be determined by the second string.

```py
In [1]: True and 'bot'
Out[1]: 'bot'

In [2]: 'bot' and True
Out[2]: True

In [3]: 'bot' and 'not'
Out[3]: 'not'

In [4]: 'not' and 'bot'
Out[4]: 'bot'
```

Therefore, your `"bot" and "not"` evaluation gives you `"not"` and the bot will react to any message that has the word "not" in it.

You need to change your condition to check for both words individually and react only if both checks pass